# How to save a custom cookie

Tags: django, django-views

Is there a way to save a cookie that is available on other site ?

For instance I have my django project on http://www.example.com and I want that django saves a cookies for a site written in PHP on http://site.Idontknow.com .

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.

Longer answer is that while you can't do it directly you could include a resource in your page, like an image or a small page loaded in an iframe or similar, which came from the 3rd party site which in turn set its own cookie. Not exactly secure or reliable.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. Browsers do not let you set cookies on other sites, for (hopefully) obvious security reasons.